# setting the TabItem IsSelected background

Tags: c#, wpf, styling, tabitem

I can't seem to control the background color of the selected tab. I can use the IsSelected trigger to control the value of the non-selected tabs however.

This code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#EE444444" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

works, in setting the un-selected tabs background to pink. However, the selected tabs following some light gray color I can't get rid of.

I also tried this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#EE444444" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but none of these have any affect on selected tab. The only thing I can think of is that some referenced assembly has a generic tab style?

This style is located in the same file as the tab control, in the `Grid.Resources` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the TabItem selection behaviour is defined at the Template level. If you want to change the color, define a whole new DataTemplate, and define triggers in that template to change color. Then define that template as the ItemTemplate of your TabControl.